# Write to the same file from different MPI processes

Tags: mpi, race-condition

I have some MPI processes which should write to the same file after they finish their task. The problem is that the length of the results is variable and I cannot assume that each process will write at a certain offset.

A possible approach would be to open the file in every process, to write the output at the end and then to close the file. But this way a race condition could occur.

How can I open and write to that file so that the result would be the expected one?

Comment: Some sample code illustrating what you're trying to do would help us better understand your requirements.  But from what I understand you're trying to do, I'd say [Mpi_file_write_shared](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_File_write_shared.html)  or [Mpi_file_write_ordered](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_File_write_ordered.html) are the usual ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might think you want the shared file or ordered mode routines.  But these routines get little use and so are not well optimized (so they get little use... quite the cycle...)

I hope you intend on doing this collectively.  then you can use MPI_SCAN to collect the offsets, then call MPI_FILE_WRITE_AT_ALL to have the MPI library optimize the I/O for you.

(If you are doing this independently, then you will have to do something like... master slave? passing a token? fall back to the shared file pointer routines even though I hate them?)

Here's an approach for a good collective method:

```
incr = (count*datatype_size);

/* you can skip this call and assume 'offset' is zero if you don't care
   about the contents of the file */
MPI_File_get_position(mpi_fh, &offset);

MPI_Scan(&incr, &new_offset, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG_INT, 
                      MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
new_offset -= incr;
new_offset += offset;

ret = MPI_File_write_at_all(mpi_fh, new_offset, buf, count,
                              datatype, status);
```